# Do obstacles slow down troops in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I noticed that when attacking in multiplayer, my ground troops avoid running through obstacles such as trees. Instead the troops walk around the tree (or other obstacle).

I’m wondering if obstacles actually slow the troops on their way to a building or if their horizontal/vertical/diagonal speed is still the same?

I also wonder if anyone has tried to place obstacles (using a shovel) as an actual defense advantage?

Here’s a funny base my friend came across once:[image: Trees inside walls!]

Comment: Funny how I colored over the names and clans, but you can still see the clan of the person my friend attacked on the clan castle. *Facepalm*

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that allowing such obstacles on your base makes it much harder to switch and edit base layouts. Even tombstones from a prior attacker will prevent you from activating a base-layout without removing them or modifying and editing your layout. With that in mind, any benefits are costing you in flexibility and better base design.

Plus, obstacles also operate as gaps in the footprint of buildings, allowing attackers to place troops behind walls and closer to surrounding buildings.

Last but not least, you miss out on the gems you get from clearing them, along with XP points and bonus gems.

Comment: I appreciate the answer (although it doesn't answer it, normally this might be better as a comment which you unlock at 50 reputation). Looking back, I asked the question sort of as a joke even though it implied that I thought it could be a strategy.

Answer (score 1):

No obstacles don't slow down troops and if they do it would be probably like 0.000001% slower so u would have to place a lot of obstacles for it to make the slightest difference.

Although it could make troops reroute to attack some other building.

Answer (score 0):

Obstacles only affect placement of troops. You cannot deploy a troop on top of an obstacle, but it does not seem to affect troops in any other way. For instance, giants still walk past / over the bush obstacle, instead of around it, if you put them in a nice row, as opposed to walls, which stop or divert troop pathing.

You can learn more about pathing here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashOfClans/comments/2y614j/misc_strategy_troop_pathing_explained_maybe/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

Comment: Actually, you can deploy troops on top of obstacles. Check the screenshot I put on my question, my friend spawned troops in his base

Comment: You can even see the spawning rectangle by the farthest left tree behind walls. And I also had goblins walk around a tree the day I asked this question, so they don’t just walk through them